# How to read a .pst file using c# code

Tags: c#, pst

I'm using visual studio 2008 and i want to read a .pst file using c# code and want to display the contents of the pst file on a webpage?
please let me know the detailed procdedure of doing that.

Thanks
Satish

Comment: Why you would want to do that is beyond me; a big security issue if you ask me. You could start by looking at the PST file format; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: ^Just because you don't know the 'why' doesn't mean there isn't a valid reason.
OP:  See Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx / MailItem ) - Search Example -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184592(v=office.14).aspx